# GWT and Google App Engine: Splitting Login and Primary Apps

Tags: java, security, google-app-engine, gwt

I recently watched a video from Google I/O on Best Practices for GWT Security, and one of the strong recommendations from the speaker was to actually separate your app into two different apps:

- **Login App** - used to present a login screen and authenticate a user for the Primary App; and
- **Primary App** - the rest of your app

His reasoning for this is that all client-side code can be compromised, even with GWT's insane obfuscation methods. Don't open yourself up to unnecessary attack, so by having two separate apps, an attacker (who is not authorized to even login and use the system) will only be able to pull down the client-side code of the *Login App* without getting his hands on the *Primary App*'s client-side code.

I like this approach, but plan on deploying my app(s) to GAE, which strictly prohibits you from using multiple apps (WARs) to coordinate with each other (explicitly says so in the Terms & Conditions!).

So it seems that the Google Developers themselves have a disagreement here! On one hand, the GWT team wants your app broken up for security purposes, but then the GAE team doesn't want 2+ apps being "in league" with each other for billing purposes. My impression is that Google *wants* developers to embrace their entire platform, using both GWT and GAE.

So what's the deal here?!? Is there any way to break up my codebase without producing a separate WAR (thus appeasing GAE) but in such a way that there's no way to see my *Primary App*'s code until you log in?

I would think "yes", however GWT forces you to download everything all at once (to minimize roundtrips and expensive HTTP requests). Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the idea would be to have separate modules in GWT to do the login and run the real application.

You might see for example:
https://github.com/ashtonthomas/GwtAdvancedLogin

> This Google Web Toolkit (GWT) application is an example of how to
>   create a separate Login Module which then funnels to one or many other
>   modules that contain the main applicaiton login.
>
> You can use this type of setup to take full control over you login
>   page while not including it in your main module.

BTW, Gwt does not force you to download everything at once.  You can easily split the code.
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting

I would think having separate modules is what you want though as opposed to code splitting though.

Comment: Wow, great answer @user1258245 (+1) - thanks! So if I'm not mistaken, every GWT module ends up being its own HTML file, right? That way I can deploy both HTML files (modules) with the same WAR and configure my URL mapping to direct users accordingly. Is this correct or am I off-base? Thanks again!

Comment: Also have a look at my guice-rf-activities archetype in https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes which offloads authentication to the container. Would work with minor modifications on App Engine, with Google Accounts auth or your own auth. The samples in GWT SDK also have App Engine auth built-in, and they'll be updated for GWT 2.5.

Comment: @pnongrata yes you can deploy both modules within the same war.  As for the module having it's own HTML file, I think that is an implementation detail.  Yes you could, but no it's not required.  I tend to think along the lines of one html page and code splitting (loading the main module after authentication) but you might check out Thomas Broyer's suggestion.  He knows 100x better than I.