# GWT: How to download EntryPoint after authenticating?

Tags: java, authentication, gwt, module

The idea here is to have my GWT app in 2 different modules:

1. `WebModule` (entry point) that simply contains a login screen; and
2. `AppModule` (entry point) that contains the main application

When users go to the website, the `WebModule` downloads into their browser and presents a login screen to them. They must then submit a username and password, which then uses GWT-RPC to authenticate them and determine if they are allowed to proceed.

If authentication passes, I would like the `AppModule` to be downloaded, which has its own starting `Place` (and respective view/presenter), and I would like the user to be redirected to that place.

How could I implement this functionality? Both:

- Forcing the `AppModule` to download only upon successful login; and
- Redirecting the user to the `AppModule`'s starting place?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: IMHO for a simple authentication page, you might not want to bother a whole GWT 
module.

Have a look at the [Dynamic Host Page](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/dynamic_host_page.html) article in the official GWT site. It's a bit outdated, but analyzes some auth use cases that you might find yourself in. The simpler way could be to dynamically provide your `AppModule`'s host page only on a successful login on a simple servlet-based login page.

See also this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914180/gwt-and-google-app-engine-splitting-login-and-primary-apps) post, if you want to go with dual module structure.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply adding Spring Security to your GwT web application. You can then use the Spring Security login page (customizable) and work with a a local user list, LDAP, etc. Would also support guest user if applicable.

Visit http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/ for more info and Google "gwt spring security" if you need guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm plaing with panels.
My GWT applications have a structure:

public class Courses implements EntryPoint {

....all variables

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Login - select from database all user
    //
    statusMessage.setText("Waiting for users list.");
    String message = new String();
    myDatastoreService.loginSelect(message,
            new AsyncCallback<List<LoginInfo>>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
            Window.alert(error.getMessage());
        }

        public void onSuccess(List<LoginInfo> result) {
            statusMessage.setText("");
            loginInfo = result;
            if (loginInfo.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Empty");
                UserDialog createUser = new UserDialog();
                createUser.userInfo("F", -1, currentUser,
                            userTable, loginInfo, statusMessage);
            } else {
                loginDialog();
            }
        }
    });
    RootPanel.get("statusPanelContainer").add(statusMessage);
}
// Login dialog:
private void loginDialog() {
    //Here you have to put all panels you need for login
    // If login is successfully : you have to remove all login panels from main panels (not root)
    // and call main dialog
     mainDialog();
    // If login is not successfully you stay on login panel

}
private void mainDialog() {
    // Here you put all your applications mains panels
}
```

}